# Ayuda con bptest en Rstudio

Tags: r

Estoy aplicando el bptest para ver la heterocedasticidad de una regresión lineal la cual es ésta

```
fit4 <- lm(datos$promedio_total ~ datos$hv + datos$Municipal+ datos$P_Pagado + datos$desempeño_medio +datos$desempeño_alto +datos$desempeño_insuficiente + datos$cod_rural_rbd)
```

Donde promedio total es el promedio de una prueba, Municipal - Particular Pagado son clasificaciones de los establecimientos, desempeños son como están categorizados los colegios y cod_rural es una variable dummy 1 si es un colegio rural y 0 si es urbano.

Al hacer el bptest se entrega lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe que significa el BP sea 110.7 y el df 7? 
De antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Ya leíste la documentación de la función? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lmtest/versions/0.9-36/topics/bptest Tus resultados te dicen básicamente que tienes problemas de heterocedasticidad...

Answer (score 0):

En estadística, el test de Breusch-Pagan se utiliza para determinar la heterocedasticidad en un modelo de regresión lineal. Analiza si la varianza estimada de los residuos de una regresión dependen de los valores de las variables independientes. Suponiendo el modelo: y = Xβ + e, en forma matricial. Entonces lo que usted quiere contrastar es las hipótesis. H0: Homocedasicidad (ésto es, la varianza de los residuos es constante) vs H1: Heterocedasticidad.

Entonces como el estadístico es una χ² en este caso con 7 grados de libertad y el estadístico obtenido es BP = 110. 7, tenemos que, en su caso se rechaza H0, según el valor p obtenido, y tiene problemas de Heterocedasticidad.

```
valor.p = pchisq(110.7,7,lower.tail = F)
ifelse(valor.p < 0.05, "Rechazo H0: Homocedasticidad", "No rechazo H0: Heterocedasticidad")
[1] "Rechazo H0: Homocedasticidad"
```